# Aesthetic of a chemical compound

Tags: chemfig

I am drawing the following chemical compound

```
\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{\textcolor{green}{CH_3}-C(-CH_2-CH_2?[a])(-[:-45,,1,1]CH_2-CH_2?[e])-[:45,,1,1]CH_2-CH_2-[:-45,,1,1]C?[a]?[e]-CH(-[:-45,,1,1]CH_2?[b])-[:45,,1,1]CH_2-[:-45,,1,1]C?[b](-[:-60,,1,1]CH_2-CH_2?[c])-[:60,,1,1]CH_2-CH_2-[:-60,,1,1]CH?[c]-C(-[:45,,1,1]CH_2?[d])(-[:-45,,1,1]CH_2?[f])-CH_2-C?[d]?[f]-\textcolor{red}{CH_3}}
```

But it turns out that the arrival and departure atoms do not match, and that the atoms are clumped together. Can anyone fix this, and suggest a better alignment of the atoms?

Some of the problems include:

1. The left part is clumped together, it should be something like this:
   [image]
2. Each of the bonds is connected to C (and not H)
3. The rightmost part should have something like this:
   [image]
   The atoms should be aligned, forming a square.

---

**Remark** (from @MS-SPO):

The code which should have been posted here probably would be something like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone} % 3.1: guessed class
\usepackage{chemfig}% 3.2: guessed missing package

\begin{document}% 3.1: missing

\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{\textcolor{green}{CH_3}-C(-CH_2-CH_2?[a])(-[:-45,,1,1]CH_2-CH_2?[e])-[:45,,1,1]CH_2-CH_2-[:-45,,1,1]C?[a]?[e]-CH(-[:-45,,1,1]CH_2?[b])-[:45,,1,1]CH_2-[:-45,,1,1]C?[b](-[:-60,,1,1]CH_2-CH_2?[c])-[:60,,1,1]CH_2-CH_2-[:-60,,1,1]CH?[c]-C(-[:45,,1,1]CH_2?[d])(-[:-45,,1,1]CH_2?[f])-CH_2-C?[d]?[f]-\textcolor{red}{CH_3}}

\end{document}% 3.1: missing
```

obtained from running through this [checklist](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790), where only the OP can check and evaluate steps 3.3 and 3.4

[image: result]

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have so far, so that others do not have to start from scratch.

Comment: FYI: added some guess of what your code should have looked like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{
    \textcolor{green}{CH_3}-C
        (-[:-45,1.41]CH_2-CH_2?[a])
        (-[:45,1.41]CH_2-CH_2?[e])
    -CH_2-CH_2-C?[a]?[e]-CH
        (-[:-60]CH_2?[b])
    -[:60]CH_2-[:-60]C?[b]
        (-[:-60]CH_2-CH_2?[c])
    -[:60]CH_2-CH_2-[:-60]C?[c]H-C
        (-[:45,1.41]CH_2?[d])
        (-[:-45,1.41]CH_2?[f])
    -CH_2-C?[d]?[f]-\textcolor{red}{CH_3}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adjust the length of the bond by setting the second parameter of the bond options to something other than 1. Here, I chose 1.41 to have the molecules aligned properly. But you can also choose another angle. I also changed the position of anchor `c`, because I think that both bonds should arrive at the C atom.

You also said that you want to make more clear that then bonds start and end at the C atoms, so, you might want to set the anchors at the right places and use the third parameter of the bond options to select the right starting atom. So this could be the result (but you can't really have the bonds *always* start and end at the C atom in this representation, especially not when positioned horizontally):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{
    \textcolor{green}{H_3C}-C
        (-[:-45,1.41]CH_2-C?[a]H_2)
        (-[:45,1.41]CH_2-C?[e]H_2)
    -CH_2-CH_2-C?[a]?[e]-CH
        (-[:-60,,1]C?[b]H_2)
    -[:60,,1]CH_2-[:-60,,1]C?[b]
        (-[:-60]CH_2-C?[c]H_2)
    -[:60]CH_2-CH_2-[:-60,,1]C?[c]H-C
        (-[:45,1.41]C?[d]H_2)
        (-[:-45,1.41]C?[f]H_2)
    -CH_2-C?[d]?[f]-\textcolor{red}{CH_3}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, you can make use of the last parameter of the bond options to put Ti*k*Z options which may be interesting to shorten bonds a bit. Play around with angles and lengths and you might get a somewhat pleasing result (but I would stick to the first version actually, because again the bonds don't *always* start and end at the C atoms and I think it is sufficiently clear anyways that the bonds are connected to the C atoms):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[atom sep=24pt]{
    \textcolor{green}{H_3C}-C
        (-[:45,1.41]CH_2-[,1.25]C?[a]H_2)
        (-[:-45,1.41]CH_2-[,1.25]C?[e]H_2)
    -CH_2-CH_2-C?[a]?[e,,{shorten <=2pt}]-CH
        (-[:-45,1.41,1]C?[b]H_2)
    -[:45,1.41,1]CH_2-[:-45,1.41,1]C?[b]
        (-[:-45,1.41]CH_2-C?[c]H_2)
    -[:45,1.41]CH_2-CH_2-[:-45,1.41,1]C?[c]H-C
        (-[:45,1.41]C?[d]H_2)
        (-[:-45,1.41]C?[f]H_2)
    -[,.85]CH_2-[,.85]C?[d]?[f,,{shorten <=2pt}]-\textcolor{red}{CH_3}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To avoid every connection of a bond to a H atom, you'd need to arrange the molecules differently, for example by stacking the atoms (and making use of @MS-SPO's suggestion of defining a `submol`. But I am unsure whether this can be considered a visually pleasing solution:

```
\definesubmol{ch}{\chembelow{C}{H}}
\definesubmol{chh}{\chembelow{C}{\phantom{_2}H_2}}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[atom sep=24pt, rotate=90]{
    \textcolor{green}{H_3C}-C
        (-[:45,1.41]!{chh}-!{chh}?[a])
        (-[:-45,1.41]!{chh}-!{chh}?[e])
    -!{chh}-!{chh}-C?[a]?[e]-!{ch}
        (-[:-45,1.41,1]!{chh}?[b])
    -[:45,1.41,1]!{chh}-[:-45,1.41,1]C?[b]
        (-[:-45,1.41]!{chh}-!{chh}?[c])
    -[:45,1.41]!{chh}-!{chh}-[:-45,1.41,1]!{ch}?[c]-C
        (-[:45,1.41]!{chh}?[d])
        (-[:-45,1.41]!{chh}?[f])
    -!{chh}-C?[d]?[f,,{shorten <=2pt}]-\textcolor{red}{CH_3}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Updated post, sorry if unclear.

Comment: @xxxx036 Updated answer. Thanks for adding an image for clarification!

Comment: Hmmm... What about the bonds that should connect the C atoms and not H?

Comment: @xxxx036 How would you make clear, for example, that the bond from the first, green, molecule does not start from the H? If you want to make clear that the connections are always from the C, I think that you should another way of representation (for example with the molecules rotated by 90 degrees).

Comment: @xxxx036, to my understanding bonds are always to Carbon, unless you mark it as a hydrogene bond (with the special symbol provided by chemfig. However, I suggest to look for `sub-molecule` in the manual. See e.g. ch. 6 for an example abd ch. 11.1 for more details. // https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdfhttps://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf

Answer (score 1):

When we have several conjugate rings and we want to obtain an aesthetically pleasing figure, we need to reduce the number of elements in the figure.

Put only the C and H terminals, for example.

It is also recommended to use the ChemFig tools to generate the rings.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{H_3C-*6((-[:30]-[:300]?[a])---?[a](-*4(--*6([:-30](-[:10]?[b])---?[b](-CH_3)---)--))---)}
\end{document}
```

[image]